# error occured on -pix_fmt in ffmpeg while converting from .mov to mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert .mov to .mp4 using ffmpeg  my command is :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy output.mp4
```

but its giving me error like this

```
    [buffer @ 00000000059bf480] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
Last message repeated 1 times
```

[buffer @ 00000000059bf480] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:4 @ 00000000043fd8a0] Error applying options to the
 filter.
Error opening filters!

even I tried for another command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

but it converts only some part and first part is blank with sound then after some time picture is coming..

I have two Q's

1] for first command what is -pix_fmt and what value to be set for ?

2] for second command why it was giving only some part, as I am copying everything vcodec as well acodec..

please guide me ..!!

Answer (score 3):

Probably, selected profile does not support 4:2:2.

So, you need to mention the 4:2:0 by adding `"-pix_fmt yuv420p"` to the command.

Hope this will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg's "Unable to parse option value '-1' as pixel format" does occur with corrupted or harder to parse videos (although [doubted](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-October/017864.html) on the mailing list). I've had it, and the best [comment](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Problem-finding-codec-parameters-in-m4v-file-tp4667137p4667151.html) on that is to try increasing analyzeduration - as in this [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3931). Some ffmpegs/ avconvs also give a note about tinkering with probesize:

> Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 720x576, 869 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
>   Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Well, both didn't work on a file where I tried it:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x2c36940] multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x2c36940] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached

but other people's mileage may vary.

Comment: So, with -analyzeduration 2147483647 it works for me, on this one video that I'm currently having problems with. That huge number is the max you can put there (2**31-1), it also works with ten million but you know... I don't see any downside of using the highest number available.